# Qual função usar

Tags: microsoft-excel, funções

Como principiante no Excel, estou tendo dificuldades para usar uma função que acredito ser a solução para o que eu quero, a função (SE).

É o seguinte, eu tenho um somatório de valores que começam de 54 e vai a 317. Eu quero dividir esse valores em 8 (oito) classes que ficaram assim: de 54 a 86 de 87 a 119 de 120 a 152 de 153 a 185 de 186 a 218 de 219 a 251 de 252 a 284 e de 285 a 317.

A essas classes eu dei "pesos", tipo peso 1 até peso 8. Gostaria que o Excel ao identificar a que classe pertença a classifique no peso que eu determinar, exemplo 54 a 86 igual a peso 1.

Answer (score 0):

Se sua coluna de valores estiver no `A:A`, começando pelo `A2` preencha a coluna B com:

`B1 = 1` e as outras celulas, começando do B2 `=SE(MOD((A2-53); 33)=0;B1+1;B1)`

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode criar uma tabela com os valores e usar um PROCV para procurar o valor dentro do intervalo e seu correspondente

```
   A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I
 -----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
 1    |     |     |     | MIN | MAX | VAL |     |     |
 -----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
 2    |  70 |     |     |  54 |  86 |  1  |     |     |
 -----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
 3    | FRM |     |     |  87 | 119 |  2  |     |     |
 -----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
 4    |     |     |     | 120 | 152 |  3  |     |     |
 -----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

A fórmula que vai em "FRM" é:

```
FRM =PROCV(A2;E2:G3;4;TRUE)
```

A2 = É a celula onde está o valor que voce deseja localizar o peso

E2:G4 = É o intervalo onde estão os valores

3 = É o indice onde está o peso que voce procura

TRUE = Significa que voce deseja procurar por valores exatos e não aproximados

Comment: Esses valores que vão de 54 a 317 são oriundo de resultados da mega sena, ou seja, a soma de cada dezena sorteada. O menor somatório (54) é a soma de um concurso onde a soma das dezena deu esse valor, assim como o valor 317.

Comment: Essas somas estão ao lado de cada concurso sorteado. Eu os classifiquei dessa forma, em classes, para verificar quais saem mais e a frequência em que ocorrem. Não consegui entender com aplicar a função que tu falou. (procv)

Comment: Certo, mas em qual parte está sua dúvida?